# JQuery getJSON return object array from function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Is it possible to return the value of an async call like the example below without making it synchronous?

```
var allUsers;

function getUsers() {
    jQuery.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/members', function(json) {
        return json;
    });
}

allUsers = getUsers();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A callback function can't return anything because the point of the callback functions is that **you don't wait for the return**, so your callback function should implement your logic, something like that,

```
function getUsers() {
    jQuery.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/members', function(allUsers) {
        if(allUsers) {
            // you have allUsers here
            // you can do whatever your logic requires here
        }
    });
}

getUsers();
```